# Headers are not coming in node js server & verify token

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

verify Toekn error in node js i send token to post man but error found show in postman

verify token are not verify in postman send error 401

```
const jwtEmail=req.body.email.split("@")[0]

            console.log(jwtEmail)
            const token=jwt.sign({user_data:email},jwtEmail,{
              expiresIn:"24h"
            }
            )
const verifyToken=async(req,res,next)=>{
  
    try {
      const token = req.header.authorization.split("")[0];
      const user_data =await  User.findOne({auth_token:token})
      const jwtEmail = user_data.email.split("@")[0];
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token,jwtEmail);
      next(); 
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: "Auth failed",
        error
        
      });
    }
    
  }
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Konrad  {
    "message": "Auth failed",
    "error": {}
}

Comment: Add `console.log(error)` before returning

Comment: @Konrad TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Comment: Either `req.header.authorization` or `user_data.email` is `undefined`. Isn't is `req.headers` and not `req.header`?

Comment: const verifyToken=async(req,res,next)=>{
  
    try {
      const token = req.header.authorization.split(" ")[1];
      console.log(split)
      const user_data =await  User.findOne({auth_token:token})
      const jwtEmail = user_data.email.split("@")[0];
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token,jwtEmail);
      next(); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: "Auth failed",
        error
        
      });
    }
    
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
const token = req.header.Authorization.split(" ")[1];
```

and check if you are passing the token in the header correctly, it should be like this;

```
headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer YOUR-TOKEN-HERE',
    },
```

Comment: error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Comment: Check if token is passed to backend or not, try console.log(req.header.Authorization)

Comment: const verifyToken=async(req,res,next)=>{
 
    try {
      const token = req.header.authorization.split(" ")[1];
      const user_data =await  User.findOne({auth_token:token})
      const jwtEmail = user_data.email.split("@")[0];
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token,jwtEmail);
      next(); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: "Auth failed",
        error
        
      });
    }
    
  }    this is node js code

Answer (score 0):

`req.headers` should be used instead of req.header.

```js
const [type,token] = req.headers.Authorization.split(" ");
```

**Way to add headers in fetch api :**

```js
const URL = "some api URL";
const token = "token";

fetch(URL, {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
  }
})
```

Comment: Not Working When frontend Send Data then through error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Comment: is it working when headers are sent through postman?

Comment: i Am send data For react js but this code is not working

Comment: are you using axios?

Comment: export function N_getProfile(user_id,token) {
  return fetch(`${url}/get-profile-info`, {  
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    user_id:user_id
   
  }),
    auth:JSON.stringify({
      token:token
    })
})
  .then((d) => d.json())
  .catch((e) => e);
}

Comment: fetch('url', {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
  }
})

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'email')

Comment: but my api are reday is this type please help

Comment: Are the headers coming ?

Comment: New Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'email')

Comment: export function N_getProfile(user_id,token) {
  return fetch(`${url}/get-profile-info`, {  
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'
    },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    user_id:user_id
   
  }),
    auth:JSON.stringify({
      token:token
    })
})

Comment: are you finding the user via token?

Comment: Yes I am login then show user Profile

Comment: I have added another answer please check.

Comment: token are not send in headers are verifying

Comment: means? did you get token in backend server?

Answer (score 0):

**As in JWT TOKEN only user ID is stored but as in your current case you are using email so, it may be used to solve:**

```js
const jwtEmail=req.body.email.split("@")[0]

            console.log(jwtEmail)
            const token=jwt.sign({user_data:email},"SECRET_KEY",{
              expiresIn:"24h"
            }
            )
const verifyToken=async(req,res,next)=>{
  
    try {
      const [type,token] = req.header.authorization.split(" ");
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token,"SECRET_KEY");
      const user_data = await  User.findOne({email:decodedToken.user_data.email});
      const jwtEmail = user_data.email.split("@")[0];
      
      next(); 
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: "Auth failed",
        error
        
      });
    }
    
  }
```